# Configuring vhost with apache

Tags: php, apache

I have the following vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot /ebs1/apache/www/html/sites/example
    <Directory "/ebs1/apache/www/html/sites/example">
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog /ebs1/apache/log/error_log_example.com
    CustomLog /ebs1/apache/log/access_log_example.com personalizado
</VirtualHost>
```

Instead of repeating the directory "/ebs1/apache/www/html/sites/example" twice is it possible to only use it once?

Comment: No, you must declare it twice unless you have no intention of removing the ability to see file structure when an index isn't present and if you don't want any other `.htaccess` file to override all settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate `<Directory`> configuration (outside of the `<VirtualHost>` block) that covers all your virtual hosts, assuming their respective directories are below it:

```
<Directory "/ebs1/apache/www/html/sites">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: That's great! So all my virtualhosts xxx, yyy, zzz... that points to /ebs1/apache/www/html/sites/xxx,yyy,zzz will inheritance the <Directory "/ebs1/apache/www/html/sites"> options and allowoverride?